# Concrete types can't conform to protocols with constrained associated types in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I have a little problem, here is the faulty code:

```
protocol ConstraintProtocol { }

protocol AssocProtocol {
    associatedtype T : ConstraintProtocol
}

protocol MyProtocol : ConstraintProtocol { }

enum ConcreteType: AssocProtocol {
    typealias T = MyProtocol
    case a
}
```

The error states the usual `type 'ConcreteType' does not conform to protocol 'AssocProtocol'` even giving a hint: `possibly intended match 'ConcreteType.T' (aka 'MyProtocol') does not conform to 'ConstraintProtocol'`

But... `MyProtocol` **does** conform to `ConstraintProtocol`!!!

And indeed, if I remove the constraint from the `associatedtype`, it works like a charm.

So, is it just me, or did I miss something?

I'm using Swift 4.1 in Xcode 9.3.1, if it can help.

Comment: [Protocols don't always conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) – although `MyProtocol` derives from `ConstraintProtocol`, it does not currently conform to `ConstraintProtocol`, therefore it cannot be used to satisfy the associated type `T : ConstraintProtocol`.

Comment: Damnit!  Thanks for the link. I did not know that Swift specificity...